Do you need a definite article here?
Do you need the in the following sentence?

My name is Alex, but I go by the gender-neutral Sasha.

I think this definite article is warranted because the sentence above may be said to have an ellipsis:

My name is Alex, but I go by the gender-neutral [name] Sasha.

English is not my native language. Do you need a definite article here?

I would argue Yes.
The phrase:

My name is Alex, but I go by Sasha.

is absolutely valid, and I would prefer it over:

My name is Alex, but I go by the name Sasha.

However, the first case implies that everything after the word "by" is part of the name. Multi part names would work fine, as long as everything after "by" is part of the title, for example:

My name is Alex, but I go by Sasha the fourth.

Where Sasha the fourth is the name.
Adding the article does indeed imply the object (the name, in this case) and thus you can describe the object without the adjectives being possibly mistaken as part of the name (at least to my ears):

My name is Alex, but I go by the gender-neutral, beautiful, compact [name] Sasha.

You can switch the adjective gender-neutral with any other adjective describing a name, and you might notice that it would sound weird or off to say:

My name is Alex, but I go by short Sasha.

versus:

My name is Alex, but I go by the short [name] Sasha.


Thank you so much for your time and getting to the bottom of my question!

CD licenses only 'go by the name of'. Webster's licenses the 'go by' deleted form, flagged 'American English'. This is probably a US/UK divide. // As adjectives,  'gender-neutral' is classifying whereas 'short' is purely descriptive, which might explain why only certain adjectives seem to work. Or register (or even weight of adjective: 'improbable'?) might be a factor here. Good spot
